# How to keep translated pages related to the original in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-translate

How do I keep translated pages related to the original page in GA and get consolidated analytics data for a page?

For example, the original page slug looks like this: `/type/blog/database-management-software/`

The translated page slug looks like this:
`/ar/type/blog/database-management-software/`

Analytics counts them as separate URLs. How do I combine them?